# android how to seprate spanned object in edittext in xmpp?

Tags: android, xmpp

i am making a  chatting application in which i am using emoticons functionality.My Emoticons functionality  is working properly for single image ,but when i am taking multiple emotive images it is not converting in to particular image..,at a time only single image is converting, My problem is

1. i am unable to separate the spanned object in edit text field..,for single value it is working but for multiple value its is not working..

Example.i am taking 4 different images in edit text field, like this here

[image]

[image]
now i want to seprate its spanned object.,how can i do this
here is code

```
 public void keyClickedIndex( final String index) 
{

    ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() 
    {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) 
        {    
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(index, ".");
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),emoticons[Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1]);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        }
    };


    Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='"+ index +"'/>", imageGetter, null);        
    int cursorPosition = mSendText.getSelectionStart();     
        mSendText.getText().insert(cursorPosition, cs);
```

please help me..,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: separate? what you mean?

Comment: @pskink seprate mean ,i want to know the image of particular object.that in edittext it is smiley,sad or anything else

Comment: sorry, dont know what you want

Comment: @pskink can you help me..,that how to add bounty on this question??

Comment: your question is not clear: nobody will know what you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52720/discussion-between-r-t-and-pskink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use emoticon handler method

```
private static class EmoticonHandler implements TextWatcher {

    private final EditText mEditor;
    private final ArrayList<ImageSpan> mEmoticonsToRemove = new ArrayList<ImageSpan>();
    //public String txt;
    XMPPClient act;
    public EmoticonHandler(EditText editor,XMPPClient act) {
        // Attach the handler to listen for text changes.
        mEditor = editor;
        mEditor.addTextChangedListener(this);
        this.act = act;
    }

    public void insert(String emoticon, int resource) 
    {
        // Create the ImageSpan
        Drawable drawable = mEditor.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(drawable,emoticon,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

        // Get the selected text.
        int start = mEditor.getSelectionStart();
        int end = mEditor.getSelectionEnd();
        Editable message = mEditor.getEditableText();

        // Insert the emoticon.
        message.replace(start, end, emoticon);
        message.setSpan(span, start, start + emoticon.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Check if some text will be removed.
        if (count > 0) {
            int end = start + count;
            Editable message = mEditor.getEditableText();
            ImageSpan[] list = message.getSpans(start, end, ImageSpan.class);

            boolean check = false;

            for (ImageSpan span : list)
            {
                // Get only the emoticons that are inside of the changed
                // region.

                check = true;
                int spanStart = message.getSpanStart(span);
                int spanEnd = message.getSpanEnd(span);
                //txt = text.toString();
                act.emorTxt =  text.toString();
                if ((spanStart < end) && (spanEnd > start)) {
                    // Add to remove list
                    mEmoticonsToRemove.add(span);
                }
            }

            if(!check)
            {
                act.emorTxt =  text.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        Editable message = mEditor.getEditableText();

        // Commit the emoticons to be removed.
        for (ImageSpan span : mEmoticonsToRemove) 
        {
            int start = message.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = message.getSpanEnd(span);

            // Remove the span
            message.removeSpan(span);

            // Remove the remaining emoticon text.
            if (start != end) {
                message.delete(start, end);
            }
        }
        mEmoticonsToRemove.clear();


    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

}
```

it will work perfectly....:)